# mongoose populate() isn't functioning

Tags: mongoose

I tried to populate the disciplinas array of the aluno model, but only the default _id of mongoose was displayed, and no other information was displayed.

Student schema:

```js
const AlunoSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    ......

    disciplinas: [{
        disciplina: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Disciplina'
        },
         
        ...

    }]
});
```

Discipline Schema:

```js
const DisciplinaSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    nome: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    horario: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    instrutor: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});
```

Router:

```js
router.get("/:cpf", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const cpf = req.params.cpf;
        const aluno = await Aluno.findOne({ cpf })
            .populate('disciplinas.disciplina');
        if (!aluno) {
            return res.status(404).send("Aluno não encontrado!");
        }
        return res.status(200).send(aluno);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).send("Erro ao consultar aluno!");
    }
});
```

I use postman to check that only the _id appears.

```json
"disciplinas": [
        {
            "_id": "65652e456098d304bab6d1fd",
            
            ...

        }
]
```

Comment: Please post the full content of your `Router` file showing all model imports/require.